# How do you manage (Coffeescript) imports with Testacular without using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, coffeescript, karma-runner

I'm using Coffeescript for everything, and have ran into trouble trying to include `chai.js` into my test.

my `configs/testacular.conf.js` looks like this (note the relative `basePath`):

```
basePath = '../';

// Install devDependencies with `npm install` first before attempting to run Testacular!
files = [
  MOCHA,
  MOCHA_ADAPTER,
  'assets/js/lib/**/*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.coffee',
  'assets/js/*.coffee',
  'node_modules/chai/chai.js'
];

autoWatch = true;

browsers = ['Chrome'];
```

I list `node_modules/chai/chai.js` rather than include it in my sources because I would like chai to be installed via `devDependencies` with `npm install`.

My test lives in `test/unit/coolSpec.coffee` and reads like so:

```
"use strict"

should = chai.should()

# Mocha/Chai specs for controllers go here
describe "OverviewCtrl", ->
  beforeEach ->
    ctrl = new OverviewCtrl()

  it "should do something awesome.", ->
    1.should.be.a 'string'
```

But testacular fails to find `chai`.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: chai is not defined
    at /.../test/unit/coolSpec.coffee-compiled.js:5
Chrome 25.0 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.386 secs / 0 secs)
```

How can I manage Javascript imports **WITHOUT resorting to RequireJS**??

EDIT: according to the [testacular documentation here](http://testacular.github.com/0.6.0/config/files.html) the effect of listing a file in the files array is exactly that of inserting a `<script>` tag into the browser at test-time. This should mean all symbols are imported.

But then again, maybe that's the issue: http://chaijs.com/chai.js itself was written for RequireJS. I may have no choice but to use it!

Comment: Installing a dependency and having the file exist is not the same as having a reference to that function or object in your source or test file - you may be confusing the two. You still need to actually include chai in your code, whether with Node.js's require system, inlining the source, or indeed with something like RequireJS. It's also possible that I'm misunderstanding your question...

Comment: I think you're largely right in that. I would assume that Testacular does inlining for us, but `chai.js` isn't written in a style where you can just have it inlined. Sadly testacular doesn't supply node's `require` so that wouldn't work either. Looks like options are limited!

Comment: One way to rephrase my question is "**what is Testacular's idiomatic way of including test dependencies?**". Surprisingly, the answer seems to be 'RequireJS', even though there's no reason for it, especially when `chai.js` can just be served straight from the test server.

Comment: Second thoughts, it's does seem necessary, given that the server must load a number of test resources from the server asynchonously, and may only start executing the test code once all resources have become available.

Comment: http://rzrsharp.net/2012/08/01/client-side-testing-insanity.html seems to clear up some of the themes in this discussion on client-side Javascript testing.

Comment: If you've researched an adequate answer on your own, it would be helpful for future readers if you compiled it and answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [chai's home page](http://chaijs.com/) and then select to download the BROWSER version of chai script, not the one for NodeJS.

The direct link to the chai script you can use in the browser for testing is here: http://chaijs.com/chai.js

Comment: I solved my problem by using another bootstrap project.  However, I believe your answer might help others so I've accepted it.